# Programmatically inactivate Record Type

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, record-type

Is it possible to programmatically inactive a Record Type?

I'm attempting to write a unit test where I insert a testCase but then need to inactive the Record Type for that testCase somehow. The reason for this is that if a user tries to clone a Case with an inactive Record Type they will get a warning saying that's not allowed. We have a custom clone button and a clone() method that checks whether a Case that is being cloned has an active Record Type. So far, I've been unable to write a unit test for this. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
private class CaseCloneControllerTest {

    @isTest
    public static void testCloneCaseInactiveRT(){
        Test.startTest();
        Case testCase = (Case)SmartFactory.createsObject('Case');
        String strRecordTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Case' AND IsActive = true LIMIT 1].Id;
        testCase.RecordTypeId = strRecordTypeId;
        insert testCase;

        System.runAs(TestUserFactory.getWwtIntegrationUser()) {
            RecordType rt = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Id = :testCase.RecordTypeId];
            rt.isActive = false;
        }

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(testCase);
        CaseCloneController controller = new CaseCloneController(sc);
        PageReference pr = controller.cloneCase();
        //System.assertEquals(null, controller.clonedCase.Id);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried in your test class to use seeAllData=true ?

Comment: it's better if you share you code or to tell what error are you getting

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am currently using seeAllData=true. I'm not getting any errors at the moment but I have not been able to figure out how to inactivate the Record Type for testCase after testCase has been inserted. I'm a beginner so there may be something simple that I'm missing on how to accomplish that or maybe it's not possible but I don't have any other ideas at the moment.

Comment: as @Santanu Boral mentioned, you cannot perform DML operations in RecordType

Comment: @ihssan using `seeAllData=true` is almost always a bad idea, and should hardly ever be suggested.

Comment: @Adnan if you are satisfied with the answer, can you please accept and close this question so that other members can find it useful

Answer (score 4):

> Recordtype object doesn't support DML operation, so you cannot create a RecordType from Apex. 
>   See [sObjects That Don’t Support DML Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_dml_objects.htm)

There are 2 ways you can do testing.

**Approach 1**

Create a recordtype at your org and make it `inactive` and try to use the recordtype in your test class.

```
System.runAs(TestUserFactory.getWwtIntegrationUser()) {
         RecordType rt = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = :recordTypeName 
                         AND SObjectType = 'Case' 
                         AND isActive=false];           
    }
```

**Approach 2**

You can create a mock in `cloneCase()` method of your Controller and do testing with `Test.isRunningTest()` and show the error message.

Comment: approach 1 is fragile as some sysad in the future could easily delete the recordtype for wondering why it is there

Answer (score 1):

This is where the Separation of Concerns [Selector pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Selector_Layer) comes in handy - I personally prefer the implementation used in Force.com Enterprise Architecture and now on Trailhead. You create a class `RecordTypesSelector` that extends `fflib_SObjectSelector` and you add various methods like `getRecordTypesByDeveloperName(String[] listOfDevNames)`

The methods in the selector layer are easily mocked ; see [AndyInTheCloud blog post](https://andyinthecloud.com/2015/03/22/unit-testing-with-apex-enterprise-patterns-and-apexmocks-part-1/) for the technique.

For a given unit test, you provide a mock implementation of `getRecordTypesByDeveloperName(String[] listOfDevNames)` that can return a `RecordType` sobject that is inactive while for Production code, the actual selector layer query executes and real database sobjects are returned.